# Htaccess rewrite rule compeletly works in localhost but only partially working on server

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have run into a problem where my htaccess rewrite commands are working on localhost but they are partially working when uploaded to the server.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Multiviews
#Turn Rewrite Engine on
RewriteEngine on
#rewrite for pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteRule ^about about.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^archive archive.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^privacy privacy.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^terms terms.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contact contact.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^submit submit.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) article.php?article_id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

All singular rewrite rules below work fine **both** on localhost and on the server:

```
RewriteRule ^about about.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^archive archive.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^privacy privacy.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^terms terms.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contact contact.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^submit submit.php [NC,L]
```

When I try the rewrite rule with a url query string it doesnt seem to work on the server but works fine in localhost:

```
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) article.php?article_id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

I have attempted to try and make it work by only querying the id but to no avail:

```
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+) article.php?article_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

The end result which I'm looking for is www.website.com/article/123/article-title

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your first 2 conditions they are being applied to a diffrent rule,

change

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: I have done what you asked but it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below rule one at a time

Rule 1

```
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/article.php?article_id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

Rule 2

```
RewriteRule ^/article/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/article.php?article_id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

requesting the link `www.website.com/article/123/article-title`. 
If these doesn't work. Then change the flags from `[NC,L]` to `[L,R=301]` (for testing purpose only) for both rules and tell me what the browser address bar shows after requesting the url in both cases(In here i have changed from internal redirect to external redirect. So the redirected address should be there in browser address bar).

Update:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Multiviews
#Turn Rewrite Engine on
RewriteEngine on
#rewrite for pages
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/article.php?article_id=$1&title=$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^about about.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^archive archive.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^privacy privacy.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^terms terms.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contact contact.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^submit submit.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: I have done what you asked but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: the first rule does not work on localhost  and on the server I get a blank white screen when I switch the rule one from NC to r=301 I get the same results. I get the exact same result as above for the second rule, and for both rules, I did get www.website.com/article/123/article-title in the address bar but no page

Comment: After changing from `[NC,L]` to `[L,R=301]`.  When you request  `www.website.com/article/123/article-title` from the browser, then the browser should have shown `www.website.com/article.php?article_id=123&title=article-title` in the address. But are you saying that the requested link doesn't change in the address bar of browser?